# Why does my Python script run in Pycharm but not in Anaconda prompt?

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I am new to coding so apologies in advance if I'm missing crucial information or my question doesn't make sense.

I made a conda environment within Pycharm and installed all the packages I need via Pycharm. My Python script works perfectly when run within Pycharm, however, when I try to run my script via the Anaconda prompt (once I have already activated my conda env) it does not work. The error message is: 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Bio''. If I check which packages are installed in my environment using conda list, I can see that the package Biopython is installed, which contains Bio. Why can it not find Bio if Biopython is installed in my environment?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the module is called Biopython, maybe you need
`from Biopython import Bio`
but it's hard to say if you do not post your code.

Comment: At the top of your script, before all other imports, can you add `import sys` followed by `print(sys.executable)`. Then run your script through pycharm and through the anaconda command prompt. Is the output of that line the same in both scenarios?

Comment: @FlyingTeller, Thank you for your reply! So I just got round to doing this and no, they are not the same. When I run the script via the anaconda prompt, it seems it uses the version of Python in my Programs folder whereas when run in Pycharm it is using the version within my conda env. Do you know why when my conda env is activated it wouldn't be using the version of python installed there?

Comment: Probably an issue with how you call your script from anaconda command propmt. Which command are you using `py` or `python`? Does it make a difference in your case?

Comment: Embarrassingly, I didn't use py or Python... I just pasted the path to the script into the command prompt. When I used the python command it worked as expected, thank you very much for your help!